# Is it possible to display magento products list block inside a custom module

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'm building a magento module and some of its functionality requires that I display a filtered set of product results. Now ideally I'd like to use magento's own product list block for this so I don't have to rebuild the layout/pagination etc... is it possible to incorporate this block into my modules template?

Alternatively is it possible to load the magento category but apply the same filter to it? In my case a specific set of SKU's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can use defaul product collection and toolbar to display in your custom module

just follow below instruction carefully.

in your **block** should look like

```
<?php

class NAMESPACE_YOURMODULE_Block_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_brand;

    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'catalog/product_list_toolbar';

    protected $_brandCollection;

    public function getBrand()
    {
        $brandId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('brand_id', false);
        if (is_null($this->_brand)) {
            if ($brandId) {
                $this->_brand = Mage::getModel('namespace_yourmodule/yourmodule')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load($brandId);
            } else {
                $this->_brand = Mage::getSingleton('namespace_yourmodule/yourmodule');
            }
        }
        return $this->_brand; 
    }

    protected function _getBrandCollection() 
    {
        if (is_null($this->_brandCollection)) {

           $helper = Mage::helper('namespace_yourmodule');

          $brandId = $this->getBrand()->getBrand();

            $this->_brandCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
            $this->_brandCollection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

            $this->_brandCollection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_brandCollection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter($helper->getBrandsAttributeCode(), $brandId);        
        }

        return $this->_brandCollection;
    }

    public function getBrandCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getBrandCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $brand = $this->getBrand();
        $helper = Mage::helper('namespace_yourmodule');
        // create breadcrumbs for page
        if ($breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
                $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', array('label'=>$helper->__('Home'), 'title'=>$helper->__('Go to Home Page'), 'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()));
                $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('brands_list', array('label'=>$helper->__('Brands'), 'title'=>$helper->__('Brands'), 'link'=>Mage::getUrl('brands')));
                $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('brands_view', array('label'=>Mage::getModel('namespace_yourmodule/yourmodule')->getBrandName($brand->getBrand(), Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()), 'title'=>$brand->getIdentifier()));
        }


        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }


    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {  
        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        $collection = $this->_getBrandCollection();

        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        } 

        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
            'collection' => $this->_getBrandCollection()
        )); 

        $this->setProductCollection($collection);

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {   
        if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
            if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
                return $block;
            }
        }
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
        return $block;
    }

    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }

    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_brandCollection = $collection;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

your **layout xml** of custom module looks like

```
   <brand_index_view translate="label">

           <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>two_columns_left</name></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="namespace_brand/view" name="brand_info" template="brand/view.phtml" >
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </brand_index_view>
```

and your **view.phtml** file looks like

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_collectionSize = $_products->getSize()): ?>

    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>

    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_products->getItems()) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
            <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(94, 120) ?>" width="94" height="120" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h2>
                     <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <div class="desc std">
                    <?php echo  $_product->getShortDescription() ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                </div>
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span>Add To Cart</span></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid first odd">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
            <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(94, 120) ?>" width="94" height="120" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
            </a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h2>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span>Add To Cart</span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products->getItems())): ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

i know it is very long process but just try i am sure you will sure done with this. Also please check with variable name with your custom module and class name also.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks! I've not tested it yet but hopefully it does what I want.